# Chemistry icon doesn't appear on Realtime Network Questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, favicon, realtime-questions

I just saw this question on the Real Time Network Questions:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But the favicon of Chemistry is not it's beta icon, it has a graduated design:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

[It got this design 2 days ago, according to Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4964/chemistry), but that seems a little while for it to be caching...

It also isn't updated on Area51:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: http://cdn.sstatic.net/chemistry/img/favicon.ico is still showing the old beta icon for me even after a hard refresh and viewing in a different browser that I never visited the site from.

Comment: So it seems it needs updating there.

Comment: I am seeing the new Chemistry favicon now, and I saw it earlier today, probably 2 to 3 hours ago.  Either it addressed after you posted it or it is localized in some fashion

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm still seeing the old one on the CDN

Comment: The site waited 3 years for graduation; give the icon 3 weeks to propagate in all the places. Or 6... or 8.

Comment: @Yes it just seems to be a while... And even on my no-history-no-cookies browser, it's still the beta icon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd tag this [status-caching](/questions/tagged/status-caching) if I could. :)

The CDN caches pretty aggressively and we normally just let it do its thing for favicons in a few places.

Comment: When should we get it in the UK? Is it days or weeks?

Comment: @Tim A few days.

Answer (score 6):

Must be a localized issue as I have no issue seeing it on the Stack Exchange question list and on the hot question side-bar.

In fact, I first noticed the new favicon on the hot question side-bar before I even saw this question (about 12:30 UTC today).

> [image]
>
> [image]

And the CDN is showing the correct favicon as well.

> [image]

Given you and [ChrisF's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256544/chemistry-icon-doesnt-appear-on-realtime-network-questions/256567#comment836670_256544) respective profiles identify you as residents of the United Kingdom, that seems to fit with the idea of a localized issue.  I am in the northeast United States and it works for me.  Via proxy, you, in fact, [confirmed that it was working in other regions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256544/chemistry-icon-doesnt-appear-on-realtime-network-questions/256567#comment836788_256567).

I know it has been 2 days since the new design went public, but I would wait it out a little longer.  Obviously the update has reached some people, but it might just be slow in propagating.

Comment: Still not getting it, but at least it's updating.

Comment: @Tim I noticed both you and ChrisF, who commented initially, are in the UK.  Might be a connection there.  I am in the US.

Comment: Sound like it... Let me try a proxy. Yeah proxy sees it. Just updating.